# Prove an inequality using Cauchy-Schwarz.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Can someone help me prove this:

Let $ \textbf{x} \in R^k. $ Show that if there exist a number $c \geq  0$ such that

$ \textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{y} \leq c \cdot ||\textbf{y}|| $ 
for all $\textbf{y} \in R^k$,

then $||\textbf{x}|| \leq c$

I have tried using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality without succcess.

Comment: What if **y** = **x**?

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I guess I didn't really know that I could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=0$, nothing to prove. If not, choose $y=x$, then $\|x\|^{2}\leq c\|x\|$, now dividing both side by $\|x\|$.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, I appreciate it!